# How to inherit from NilClass or how to simulate similar function

Tags: ruby, truthiness

I just want to use Null Object Design Pattern, but I found I can inherit from NilClass.

I can write a method "nil?" and return false but what if user write code below

```
if null_object 
  puts "shouldn't be here"
end
```

For clarify what I try to do is:

```
record = DB.find(1)
# if it can not find record 1, the bellow code should not raise exception
record.one_attr 
# and what's more
if record 
  puts "shouldn't be here"
end
# I don't want to override all NilClass
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? The *whole point* of the Null Object Refactoring is *not* to use `nil`, so why would you want to inherit from `NilClass` for that?

Comment: Just to clarify: if `null_object` is an object of your custom null object class, you're wanting `if null_object` to mean that `"shouldn't be here"` **won't** be printed out?

Comment: Did you mean to say "I **can** inherit from NilClass", or "I **can't** inherit from NilClass"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach that may work for you is to overide the method #nil? in your Null object.
This means that in your code to test for null you have to use obj.nil? and not just check for obj existence. This is probably reasonable, since you can distinguish between nil and null. Below is an example:

```
class NullClass
  def nil?
    true
  end

  def null_behavior
    puts "Hello from null land"
  end
end
```

Inheritance will work:

```
class NewClass < NullClass
end
```

Use like so:

```
normal = Class.new
null = NewClass.new

x = [normal, null]

x.each do |obj|
  if obj.nil?
    puts "obj is nil"
    obj.null_behavior
  end
end
```

Output:

```
obj is nil
Hello from null land
```

Just remember to use #.nil? for any checks that require Null and Nil to be false-ish.

#### Below this line was my WRONG initial answer

```
CustomNil = Class.new(NilClass) 

class CustomNil
  def self.new
    ###!!! This returns regular nil, not anything special.
  end
end
```

[tests deleted for brevity]

Use at your own risk. I haven't researched what side effects this may cause or whether it will do what you want. But it seems it does have some nil like behavior

Comment: Thanks, what risk do you think it have?

Comment: I've edited my response to answer your question and show where my original response was mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of inheriting from `NilClass` I do the following

```
class NullObject < BasicObject
  include ::Singleton

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    if nil.respond_to? method
      nil.send method, *args, &block
    else
      self
    end
  end
end
```

This gives you any custom method that have been monkey patched onto `NilClass` (such as ActiveSupport's `blank?` and `nil?`).  You can also of course add custom null object behaviors, or change `method_missing` to handle other calls differently (this one returns the NullObject for chaining, but you could return `nil` for example).

Comment: This is a great answer! Inheritance from `BasicObjet` is the key. `require "singleton"` is necessary to include the Singleton method. I note that `NullObject.instance.class` returns `NilClass` whereas `NullObject.instance == nil` returns `true`. Some adjustments may be necessary, depending on the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Ruby actually allows you to inherit from NilClass and create an object based on it:

```
class CustomNilClass < NilClass
end

custom_nil_object = CustomNilClass.new
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for CustomNilClass:Class
```

Comment: So why did you say "but I found I can inherit from NilClass"?